# Valums Ajax File Uploader - How to solve Firefox memory leak

Tags: ajax, memory-leaks, upload

I'm trying to use Valums Ajax File Uploader but there seems to be a memory leak with Firefox (5.0). When uploading, for example, a 4mb image, firefox.exe's memory usage goes up 16mb and never goes back down.  This doesn't happen on IE9, latest Chrome and latest Safari.

The demo is here: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Does anybody have an idea on how to get this working?
I placed an issue on GitHub here https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues/169 but I figured I should ask here.

Thanks!